# Time complexity of an unorthodox nested for loop

Tags: time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have read through few posts dealing with time complexity and loops and have a question regarding the time complexity of the following nested for loop, in order to reassure my solution:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
 for(int j = n; j > i; j--){
      #print something
 }}
```

Now I know that the time complexity of the outer loop is O(n), as the number of iterations are n.
I guess the inner loop, however, should only iterate n/2 times, as while i is counting up towards n, j is decreasing towards 0 from n in the same manner. Thus, the inner loop should stop after n/2 iterations.
Therefore, I would suggest that the time complexity is O(n*n/2) or simplified O(n^2).
Am I right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it "unorthodox"? And, although the *average* number of times the inner loop runs is N/2, it varies because i is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us see how the loop is running:

- i=0 => j will run from 1 to n => n times
- i=1 => j will run from 2 to n => (n-1) times
- i=2 => j will run from 3 to n => (n-2) times
- ............................................
- i=n-1 => j will run from n to n => 1 time

So adding all the terms, we get

```
n + (n-1) + (n-2) + .... + 1 = n*(n+1)/2
```

This equals `O(n^2)`. So yes your conclusion was correct.